# Failure to Merge Dex Android

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6Ppl.png)

The error message I am given:
Error:FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

> *What went wrong: Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
>
> > java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge
> >     dex

I have tried setting multidex to true and changing and removing lines from the app gradle as explained in similar posts but builds are still failing.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 'android-P'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.dheia.crypton"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

   }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0'
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    //adding library for search
    implementation 'com.github.mirrajabi:search-dialog:1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.AnyChart:AnyChart-Android:1.0.6'
    added dependency to Anycharts Git
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some of your dependencies is implicitly depends on different version of support libraries, here are they:

```
implementation 'com.github.mirrajabi:search-dialog:1.1'
implementation 'com.github.AnyChart:AnyChart-Android:1.0.6'
```

Especially the search-dialog which is using the following support libraries:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
```

So, you need to exclude them with the following code:

```
implementation ('com.github.mirrajabi:search-dialog:1.1') {
   exclude group: 'com.android.support'
   exclude module: 'appcompat-v7'
   exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
}
```

Then you need the same versions of support libraries for all your dependencies. So, change the following:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0'
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but the I am still getting the error.